# How to give Github Action the content of a file as input?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow with an action that creates a version number when building an artefact. This version number is written to file.

How can I give that as an input to another action?

I.e: How can I use this version number as part of a commit message in another action?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per the fabulous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60679655/4298208), there's actually an inline way to accomplish this. Not intuitive at all, except that the `::set-output...` syntax matches the same expected output format for GitHub Actions.

The below step loads the VERSION file into `${{ steps.getversion.outputs.version }}`:

```
      - name: Read VERSION file
        id: getversion
        run: echo "::set-output name=version::$(cat VERSION)"
```

I had the same use case as OP, so I'm pasting below my entire code, which does three things:

1. Pull first three-parts of the 4-part version string from the file VERSION.
2. Get a sequential build number using the `einaregilsson/build-number@v2` action.
3. Concatenate these two into an always-unique 4-part version string that becomes a new GitHub release.

```
name: Auto-Tag Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  release_new_tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Checkout source code"
        uses: "actions/checkout@v1"
      - name: Generate build number
        id: buildnumber
        uses: einaregilsson/build-number@v2
        with:
          token: ${{secrets.github_token}}
      - name: Read VERSION file
        id: getversion
        run: echo "::set-output name=version::$(cat VERSION)"
      - uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          automatic_release_tag: v${{ steps.getversion.outputs.version }}.${{ steps.buildnumber.outputs.build_number }}
          prerelease: false
```

Fully automated release management! :-)

- Note: The branch filter at top ensures that we only run this on commits to master.

Comment: where is this branch filter you are talking about

Comment: @jactor-rises - This part: `on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master`

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is [outdated as per this blog post from GitHub](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/).

It is still possible to do this as one step from your workflow though:

```
- name: Read VERSION file
  id: getversion
  run: echo "version=$(cat VERSION)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

This will set an output named `version` which you can access just as before using `${{ steps.getversion.outputs.version }}`:

```
- uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
  with:
    repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
    automatic_release_tag: v${{ steps.getversion.outputs.version }}.${{ steps.buildnumber.outputs.build_number }}
    prerelease: false
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the filesystem to communicate between actions. But if you have input on 3rd party actions, you need to give this from the outputs of another action

Ie. you need to read this file in your action and present it as output in your action.yml. Then you can use this output as input to another action in your `workflow.yaml`

Comment: While helpful in theory, this doesn't give me any guidance on how to actually accomplish the action. I want to load a file called VERSION as input into a GitHub action. Is there some already built action that can simple cat a file to an output variable? It seems like overkill to create this from scratch.