# GitHub action to simply cat a file to an output

Tags: github-actions

I want to `cat` the contents of my VERSION file (e.g. `0.9.0`) into a variable and pass it to another GitHub action as input. However, from what I can tell, this requires creating a new GitHub action just to cat the file to an 'output' which could then be used as `input` to the next module.

Is there a GitHub action that already does this - or is there some simpler solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I don't think you need to create an action for this. `cat` should be usable in a `run` step.

Try something like this:

```
      - name: Get version
        id: vars
        run: echo "version=$(cat VERSION)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Test output
        run: echo ${{ steps.vars.outputs.version }}
```

Comment: Please update to a non-deprecated version. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter

Answer (score 15):

<s>On 31 May 2023 GitHub will disable the `::set-output name=version::` syntax ([source](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/))</s>

*Update: According to the same source above, due to significant usage of these commands they are postponing the removal but still a good idea to update as per below*

You should now use:

```yaml
- name: Get version
  id: vars
  run: echo "version=$(cat VERSION)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Output stays unchanged

Comment: For info on how to use the output you've just stored in an environment variable, see here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter

Answer (score 1):

For multiline strings/files you can use the multiline syntax.
We add an empty `echo` because you need the multiline terminator to be on a separate line, and if your file doesn't have a trailing newline the command would fail.

```
steps:
  - name: Read file or arbitrary multiline value into a github actions output
    id: step_one
    run: |
      {
        echo 'output_name<<ANY_DELIMITER_YOU_WANT'
        curl https://example.com
        echo
        echo ANY_DELIMITER_YOU_WANT
      } >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

[Based on this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-a-multiline-string)